# Cassandra: can you add dynamic columns within existing column clustering?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql3, dynamic-columns

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.12 with CQL 3, and am having trouble modeling my column family.

I currently store snapshots of customer data at particular times. Works great:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  cust_id varchar,
  time timeuuid,
  data_text text,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id, time)
);
```

The cust_id is the partition key and time is the clustering id, so, as I understand it, I can think of each row in the table like:

> | cust_id | timeuuid1 : data_text | timeuuid2  : data_text |
>
> ---
>
> | CUST1   | data at this time     | data at this time      |

Now I'd like to store another group of metrics for each snapshot - but the name of each of these columns isn't fixed. So something like:

> | cust_id | timeuuid1 : data_text | timeuuid1 : dynamicCol1 | timeuuid1 : dynamicCol2 | timeuuid1 : dynamicColN |
>
> ---
>
> | CUST1   |          data         |{some value}             |{some value}             |{some value}             |

I've achieved dynamic columns for timestamp by using a composite primary key, but I can't see how to achieve this within each cluster of columns, if you see what I mean.
If I add, say, "dynamicColumnName" to the existing composite key, I'll end up with customer data stored for each dynamic column, which is not what I want.

Is this possible, without using a Map column? Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: Any help with formatting tables greatly appreciated...

Comment: CQL doesn't support "schemaless" inserts in this manner. If you have a sensible number of extra columns then you can add them to the schema. Cassandra's data store is sparse so if a column has no data it isn't filled and takes up no space. Map is an alternative, but then you have to query and pull back the full map each time - that may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info @AndySavage. Add as answer and I'll mark accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a CQL user... With the thrift API you dynamically add a column to a column family by inserting/updating a record with a value for a column with name X. The column X will start to exist right there and then for that record.

Have you tried an INSERT statement specifying a column that you have not explicitly defined? I would expect that to have the same effect (column is created).

Comment: Thanks @Ralf - unfortunately such an INSERT won't work with CQL 3 - you have to run an ALTER TABLE first. And I'm not sure how I would use that to add a column nested under the time cluster key, rather than just to the row.